# How can we install Brightscript in eclipse?

Tags: android, roku, brightscript

i needed the steps for starting brightscript projects (at least example of simple new project in brightscript )in eclipse .I dont know how to start it with eclipse .Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Read http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Eclipse+Plugin+Guide

Direct further questions to the Developer forum at http://forums.roku.com/

Answer (score 0):

Go through [Roku Developer Guide](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Developer+Guide) and follow documentation step and see the question in [Roku Developer Forum](http://forums.roku.com/viewforum.php?f=34).

Our team have written few blogs on [Roku](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blog/tagged/roku) which may helpful for you